# Configure OpenSSH server not to require password *or* key for a particular user

Tags: authentication, sshd, openssh

For the purpose of a training session, I'd like to make it possible for a particular user to connect without requiring a password or key-based authentication. I do not know the IPs or other data of the people connecting up front.

Is it possible to configure OpenSSH's `sshd` (or PAM) in a way to make this possible? How?

NB: The access will be time-limited and the access *on* the system will also be rather limited, so there is no need to point out security implications.

Comment: Well, start by training the user to enter a password for a secure session :-)

Comment: @Lambert: I'm afraid my curiosity forbids me to dodge my own question so easily. Also, there will be a password prompt as well, but that will be after the point I'm asking about, so my question stands ;)

Comment: Sure, I was just joking... Did you had a look at the `PermitEmptyPasswords` directive in `sshd_config`? Would that option be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris 11 you can use:

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

Reload `sshd`

Add a new user

```
useradd -m -d /home/testuser -s /bin/bash testuser
passwd -d testuser
```

SSH using new user

```
admin@testhost:~$ ssh testuser@localhost
Last login: Tue May 19 15:02:42 2015 from localhost
Oracle Corporation      SunOS 5.11      11.2    December 2014
testuser@testhost:~$
```

On Linux you may need to change the `UsePAM` directive to `no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I have learned that the program `sshpass` (of the same package name in Debian/Ubuntu) allows one to "enter" a password without any additional interaction. It's not ideal and not what I was looking for in my question, but I thought I'd add it in case it fits the bill for someone else.